# How to update model after http POST and DELETE in angular

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am beginning to learn Angularjs.

I have been successful in getting the data and assign it to model.

```
coreService.getCompanies().success(function(data) {
                $scope.companies = data.companies;
            });
```

However, I am not clear, how to update the model when I, insert or delete the entity.

```
categoryService.bulkDeleteCategories(companyId, selectedCategories).success(function(data) {
            console.log('success category deletion');
            $modalInstance.close('Success');
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            console.log('There was an error deleting categories' + data);

        });
```

In the above snippet, I am inserting an entity through a dialog box. The request returns 200 OK. But how do I go about updating the model now? I have been providing a refresh link which refetches the data from server and updates the model, but I am sure there must be better way.

Comment: There is missing information for answer these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### QUERY (getting all items)

Replace the scope model with your returned data, exactly as you did. (`$scope.companies` with `data.companies`)

#### INSERT

In your success handler, add the uploaded object locally to your model via `push`. That way, your model on the site gets only updated when the database got updated (aka the request was successful)

#### DELETE

In your success handler, delete the object also from your local model via `splice(index, 1)`. Again, your model on the site gets only updated when the database deleted the item (aka the request was successful)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of this approach. I will try that

Comment: You're welcome. The same works pretty good for me. Don't forget to accept my answer if it has proven useful. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough code to provide a complete answer, but add something like the following to your success function

```
$scope.companies[companyID].categories = selectedCategories
```

In other words $scope is your model and you just adjust as you would any other variable. Once you update the model, and assuming you used `$http` in the service, then your onscreen data will refresh accurately.